# Cannot store files on Heroku using Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, heroku

I deployed a simple Laravel (v5.7) app on Heroku with this config:

`filesystems.php`:

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local', 
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'), /* app/storage/app/public */
    'url' => env('PUBLIC_STORAGE_URL'), /* http://myApp.herokuapp.com/public/storage */ 
    'visibility' => 'public', 
],
```

Heroku tree:

```
app
    Procfile
    app
    database
    storage
        app
            public
    public
        storage  /* symlink to /app/storage/app/public */
```

The application works fine on Heroku except I cannot upload files to the public storage folder while it works fine locally.

I am using the following code:

```
request()->file($userSelectedFile)->store($userFolderName);
```

An example generated path looks like:

```
http://myApp.herokuapp.com/public/storage/userFolderName/kwooAGW0CrChzDbUUhOdSXsoLDI99rd1enPd22ZU.png
```

but no file is created in `app/storage/app/public/`.

How can I handle user uploads properly on Heroku?

Comment: permission to storage folder to write and read on the server?

Comment: @ViperTecPro all directories has 700 permissions

Comment: `php artisan storage:link`
Run this commend in heroku console,  Now you can access the file which you uploaded to the storage because of Symbolic link.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku provides an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). It can be used for temporary storage, but anything saved there will be lost when your dynos restart. This happens [frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day).

If you need long-term storage, Heroku [recommends using a third-party service like Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3). [Laravel supports this approach natively](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#introduction):

> Laravel provides a powerful filesystem abstraction thanks to the wonderful [Flysystem](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem) PHP package by Frank de Jonge. The Laravel Flysystem integration provides simple to use drivers for working with local filesystems, Amazon S3, and Rackspace Cloud Storage. Even better, it's amazingly simple to switch between these storage options as the API remains the same for each system.

Assuming you want to use S3, [add `league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3` and `league/flysystem-cached-adapter` to your dependencies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#driver-prerequisites), then update your `config/filesystems.php` accordingly. There should be a sample S3 configuration in there already.

Comment: the problem is that the files are not created at all! I do not care how long they stay on the server because I am just testing the app.

Comment: @Jalil, why waste time on something that won't work properly? Using S3 (or another similar service) is a quick fix, it will solve your problem, _and_ it will do it properly. I'm not sure about Laravel, but many frameworks aren't meant to serve static files in production anyway.